# How to get the user ID of all the users in a group/channel in Telegram using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am trying to get the user ID of all the users in a group/channel in Telegram using Python. I have tried using the get_chat_members() method in the telebot library, but this method is not available.

Is there any other way to get the user ID of all the users in a group/channel in Telegram using Python?

The code below works for admins but I need all the users.

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

administrators = bot.get_chat_administrators(chat_id)

print("List of Administrators:")
for admin in administrators:
    print(f"{admin.user.first_name} (ID: {admin.user.id})")

bot.stop_polling()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the answer. It is not possible to get the details with telebot.

The solution is to use TelegramClient from telethon. I will leave it here for anyone who is struggling with the same.

Credit goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74981300/15984741) person.

First, create an account [here](https://my.telegram.org), get your api_id and api_hash

Now the code below should get it done:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import asyncio

api_id = '' # Your API_ID
api_hash = "" # Your APP_ID
bot_token = "" # via botfather
group_id = Your_chat_id

async def get_users(client, group_id):
    async for user in client.iter_participants(group_id):
        if not user.deleted:
            print("id:", user.id, "username:", user.username) 

bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)

with bot:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(get_users(bot, group_id))
```